I setup a serial communication with a gas analyser but i get question mark in place of hexa value
I am using Node Serial Port to read a gas analyser. However, there are unexpected characters (????) in the data returned. How can I fix or troubleshoot this problem?
Data I received:
T-0 0.05 1.20  5799.35719.52    0    0-23.3@????

What I expected:
T-0 0.05 1.20  5799.35719.52    0    0-23.301020305

Code:
port = new SerialPort({
  path: portName,
  baudRate: baudRate,
  dataBits: 8,
  stopBits: 1,
  parity: parity,
  timeout: 100,
});

// Open the port
port.open(function (err) {
  const parser = port.pipe(new InterByteTimeoutParser({ interval: 5 }));
  // const parser = port.pipe(new ByteLengthParser({length:254}));
  parser.on("data", function (data) {
    console.log("Data received from port: ", data.toString());
    console.log("Data received from port: ", data.toString("hex"));
    console.log("Data received from port: ", data);
  });
});


What debugging have you done?

I just use electron.js node js to get data using serial communication @TangentiallyPerpendicular

It is a. gas bench made by capelac version 2.00@Yogi

I've used that module without any issues, though not that .pipe method. What do you see in a terminal emulator? Or, in *nix, if you cat /dev/ttySx? Do you have an o-scope with a digital decoder? Or another computer that can read the port? First step is to see if it's being transmitted properly. I'd also try removing the pipe method because I know it works without it.

In my serial monitor advanced in place of question mark it show ... and if i check in my developer tool of electron js it show question mark  can i use these in place of port name currently i use like COM5 @rand'Chris

Sorry, I don't understand your comment. It sounds like you're on Windows. And if you read from COM5 using something like PuTTY you get the correct values. If that's the case, there's something else wrong. If you get rid of the .pipe() and and just use stream interface via port.on("data", ... do you still get the ?? ? (Maybe something is wrong with the timeout...)
